# Tomcat doesn't show JSF exceptions

Tags: tomcat, jsf-2, tomcat7, logback

Tomcat isn't showing JSF exceptions in my log file.
I am using logback with the following config:

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your logback configuration getting properly loaded? Add `debug="true"` to your configuration and check it.

Comment: Some stuff is getting logged by some of the exceptions when there is an error page doesn't get logged. For example, when I run over jetty I seem to get a lot more exceptions being logged.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to verify.

1. Verify following jars are present in /WEB-INF/lib directory
    
   logback-access-1.0.013.jar
    
   logback-classic-1.0.13.jar
    
   logback-core-1.0.13.jar
    
   slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
2. Verify you have logback.xml placed at WEB-INF/classes directory
3. Verify your logback.xml is syntactically correct.

   ```
    <configuration>
   <appender name="fileAppender1" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
       <file>c:/kp_logs/kp-jsf.log</file>
       <append>true</append>
       <encoder>
           <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
       </encoder>
   </appender>

   <root level="DEBUG">
       <appender-ref ref="fileAppender1" />
   </root>
   ```